# How can I solve this error : Data Binding annotation processor version needs to match the Android Gradle Plugin version

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-room

I am trying to data bind my project but I am getting this error in my Gradle file I am a beginner so let me know which files you need or what other information do you need more?

> Data Binding annotation processor version needs to match the Android Gradle Plugin version. You can remove the kapt dependency androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.1.0-alpha01 and Android Gradle Plugin will inject the right version.

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
//    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
//    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.todoappstevdzaskillshare1"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
 }
} 

 dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

//DataBinding
kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.1.0-alpha01'

// Navigation Component
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

// Room components
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"

}
```

NOTE: Let me know which more files do you need and I will edit the question.

Comment: `You can remove the kapt dependency androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.1.0-alpha01 and Android Gradle Plugin will inject the right version.` ???

Comment: I guess you need to try what it asks for remove the kapt dependency `androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.1.0-alpha01` and the android gradle plugin will inject the right version for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete this line of code `kapt'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.1.0-alpha01'` and recompile. According to Google's open databinding document, the way to open databinding is:

```kotlin
android {
        ...
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
```

I think databinding is already enabled in your gradle. So just delete the dependency and this error shouldn't occur.

Comment: There are some other errors when I removed that line